# how to get values from multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want update the total of all the products in the cart page when quantity is updated.
what I tried is

```
$d=$table.each(function(){
        return Number($(this).find('.cart_price>p>span').html())*Number($(this).find('.cart_quantity_input').val());
    }).toArray();
    alert($d.length);
```

but seems its only taking the value from the first product only
I tried `.map()` yet same result.
I even tried `total+=` instead of `return` (`total=0` initialized at first) yet its returning value only from first `<tr>`.

`<tr>`'s of my HTLM inside `<table>` looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td class="cart_product">
        ...
    </td>
    <td class="cart_description">
        ...
    </td>
    <td class="cart_price">
        <p>₹<span>20</span></p>
    </td>
    <td class="cart_quantity">
        <div class="cart_quantity_button">
            <a class="cart_quantity_up" href="#"> + </a>
            <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="8" autocomplete="off" size="2">
            <a class="cart_quantity_down" href="#"> - </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cart_total">
        <p class="cart_total_price"> ₹<span>160</span></p>
    </td>
    <td class="cart_delete">
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
```

I just need the sum of each `(cart_price>span>p)*(.cart_quantity_input.val())`.

PS:`alert($d.length);` is just to check no of tr's while testing but I need sum not count

Comment: first of all what element $table is in this code.?

Comment: $table is the <table>

Comment: then your syntax says that you are trying to get the value of each table 's value as **DGS** said you should try his solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first iterate over each tr then find the values .

```
$array=$table.find('tr').each(function(){
    var price = Number($(this).find('.cart_price>p>span').html());
    var qty = Number($(this).find('.cart_quantity_input').val());
    return price*qty;
}).toArray();
alert($array.length);
```

Or to calculate Sum:

```
total=0;
$table.find('tr').each(function(){
    var price = Number($(this).find('.cart_price>p>span').html());
    var qty = Number($(this).find('.cart_quantity_input').val());
    total+= price*qty;
});
alert(total);
```

Comment: Could you format the code so its easier to read and understand?

Comment: Initially I thought it will be better to use the formatting used by the asker but yes it would be nice if any one can easily read it,thanks for suggestion

Comment: Nice, looks a lot better now. Would upvote again if i could :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$table` is a your table `$table.each()` will only run once on the table.

To have your function execute for each table row use

`$table.find('tr').each()`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each `tr` in the table and sum op the values

```
var sum = 0;
$table.find('tr').each(function () {
    sum += ($(this).find('.cart_price > p > span').text() * $(this).find('.cart_quantity_input').val()) || 0;
});
alert(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getTotalPrice(){
var quantity =$('#cart_quantity_input').val();
var price= $('#cart_price').text();

var total = quantity * price;
alert(total);
}
```

Just try using id's this worked for me.